# Kafka Ignite Sink Connector - Configuration file for Ignite

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

I want to copy my Kafka topic data to ignite node. But the case is Kafka server is running on AWS instance and Ignite on my machine. So what should be the content of my XML file which I provide to connector.properties ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the kafka worker that is connecting to your ignite cluster, needs to reference the kafka broker running in AWS. 
This is usually done in connect-standalone.properties. 
see: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/streaming/kafka-streamer#streaming-data-via-kafka-connect

```
bootstrap.servers=<public ip of your AWS kafka broker>:9092
```

This setting tells your kafka worker where to find your kafka broker.

Comment: Hi connector will be running on AWS server itself right? So it should be configured to find ignite node which is on my local machine